# \hbar new letter

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I would want to know in which package the symbol `\hbar` is defined. In fact I ask this because I need to create a letter like `\hbar` but with 'k' instead of 'h'.

Answer (score 17):

`\hbar` is defined in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\newcommand{\hbar}{\mathchar'26\mkern-9mu h}
```

So

```
\newcommand{\kbar}{\mathchar'26\mkern-9mu k}
```

should do what you want (although it might need some customization if other fonts are used).

Comment: Thank you ! I tried something like that but I made some mistakes. Where can I find the LaTex kernel under fedora ?

Comment: If you have a fairly recent TeX Live distribution, then the shell command `texdef -t latex hbar` will reveal the definition. You can then look for the "official" one in `latex.ltx`: `less $(kpsewhich latex.ltx)`