# Bold version of \hbar

Tags: math-mode

I'm using `\boldsymbol{\sigma}` to create bold versions of certain characters and math symbols.

Unfortunately this doesn't work with "h-bar": `\boldsymbol{\hbar}` produces a non-bold version of `\hbar`.

What do I need to do to get a bold version of the physical constant `\hbar`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard definition of `hbar` isn't very special: [\hbar new letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46619/hbar-new-letter)
So the following example works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\hbar\quad\boldsymbol{\hbar}$
\end{document}
```

I ***guess*** you are loading `amssymb`. This package loads `amsfonts` . The package redefines the default definition as follows:

```
\global\let\hbar\undefined
\DeclareMathSymbol\hbar  {\mathord}{AMSb}{"7E}
```

So the method `\boldsymbol` fails. The explanation is given in the ams documentation in section 9.3: *Bold math symbols*

> `\boldsymbol` can be used for a math symbol that remains unaﬀected by
>   `\mathbf` if
>   **(and only if)** your current math font set includes a bold version of that symbol. `\pmb` can be used as a last resort for any math
>   symbols that do not have a true bold version provided by your set of
>   math fonts; “pmb” stands for “poor man’s bold” and the command works
>   by typesetting multiple copies of the symbol with slight oﬀsets.�

Here an example using `\pmb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{\hbar}\quad\boldsymbol{\hbar}\quad\pmb{\hbar}$
\end{document}
```

However another method could be to use the default definition of `hbar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\hbarorig\hbar
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\let\hbar\hbarorig
\begin{document}
$\hbar\quad\boldsymbol{\hbar}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right: `amssymb` caused this issue. I decided to remove the import of this package as I'm not even using it (anymore). Thanks!