# Crossing a symbol like p, similar to one like hbar

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to cross a symbol like `p`, in math mode, similar to what we get for `h` by using `\hbar`, i.e. `ꝑ` (U+A751).

Picture in case of font problems:

[image]

Comment: How about `$\not\! p$`?

Comment: What do you mean by "It should be clear where the cross should go on `p`"? `\hbar` has the [bar] running across the top due to the ascender in `h`. Should the [bar] run across the bottom in a `p` due to the descender?

Comment: @Werner yes i think the OP must surely be picturing a `p` with a stroke through the vertical line, much as with `ħ`, or in other words, like `ƀ` reflected in the baseline. Here it is: `ꝑ` U+A751

Comment: @Werner, yes, that is what I want.

Comment: @azetina, this gives a diagonal cross over the whole symbol. I want a horizontal line across the bottom as in Au101 comment.

Comment: @passerby51 I've edited your post to clarify, feel free to make any further edits as you see fit

Answer (score 3):

Something similar has been defined by @egreg in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46619/10898). But here is a customized command:

```
\newcommand{\pbar}{\lower1.5ex\hbox{$\mathchar'26$}\mkern-6mu p}
```

Here is mwe:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\pbar}{\lower1.5ex\hbox{$\mathchar'26$}\mkern-6mu p}
\begin{document}
$\pbar$ {\large$\pbar$} {\huge$\pbar$}
\end{document}
```

Here is another take at the symbol. The extra horizontal space can be addressed with a `\!`. The vertical space has been accounted for by keeping the original height and setting the depth to 0pt.

```
\newcommand{\pbar}{\raisebox{-1.5ex}[\height][0pt]{$\mathchar'26$}\mkern-6mu p}
```

Comment: thanks. This seems good. A minor issue is that there is extra space before the symbol. Try for example `\log \pbar`.

Comment: Also, extra space below it seems: Try `\frac{\log \pbar}{n}`

Comment: @passerby51 See the updated code. Alternatively there exists the `\smash` command.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol has a Unicode code point:

```
U+A751 LATIN SMALL LETTER P WITH STROKE THROUGH DESCENDER
```

There are some (at least) text fonts, which do provide the symbol.
Example for LuaTeX/XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\DejaVuSans{DejaVu Sans}
\newcommand*{\Rows}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\TestFamily}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newfontfamily\csname FONT@#1\endcsname{#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\Rows{\RowFamily{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\TestSingle}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newfontfamily\csname FONT@#1\endcsname{#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\Rows{\RowSingle{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\RowFamily}[1]{%
  #1 & \csname FONT@#1\endcsname\symbol{"A751}
     & \csname FONT@#1\endcsname\bfseries\symbol{"A751}
     & \csname FONT@#1\endcsname\itshape\symbol{"A751}
     & \csname FONT@#1\endcsname\bfseries\itshape\symbol{"A751}
  \tabularnewline
}
\newcommand*{\RowSingle}[1]{%
  #1 & \csname FONT@#1\endcsname\symbol{"A751}
  \tabularnewline
}
\TestFamily{DejaVu Sans}
\TestSingle{Quivira}
\TestFamily{Segoe UI}
\TestFamily{FreeSerif}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  \toprule
  Name & Regular & Bold & Italic & Bold Italic\\
  \midrule
  \Rows
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The symbol could then be used inside math via `\text{\symbol{"A751}}` (package `amstext` or `amsmath`).

Comment: à propos DejaVu Sans: with current TL2016, LuaTeX 0.95 + luaotfload end up using the Condensed font. Not the case with TL2015 or xelatex.

Answer (score 2):

The width of the bar is 9mu, so we need such amount of back up.

Here's a version that works also in sub/superscripts and has no spacing issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pbar}{\mathord{%
  \text{$\m@th\mkern-2mu\raisebox{-1.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\mathchar'26$}\mkern-7mu p$}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a\pbar_{\pbar_{\pbar}}\hbar$

$ap$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was working on the horizontal spacing when I saw your post. Great job at addressing the extra spaces.

Comment: Can you add this link just as reference to what `\m@th` does and  what it is? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153398/10898